# Random Number Generator VB.NET For loop

Tags: vb.net, loops, random

I want to generate a list of random numbers between 1 and 10 in a for loop that are randomly generated, they can be duplicates. My problem at the moment is that if I use say use:

```
Dim value As Integer = CInt(Int((6 * Rnd()) + 1))
Dim index As Integer
For index = 0 to 9 
    Console.writeline(value)
Next
```

This generates a random number to begin with but then uses the same number for the rest of the loop. I am a novice to programming sorry so I may not understand anything too technical but I'll give it a go. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim rdm As New Random()

For index As Integer = 0 To 9
    Console.WriteLine(rdm.Next(1,11))
Next
```

Comment: Brilliant, that works in exactly the way I wanted it to. Thank you very much. If you don't mind, what exactly is going on in the (rdm.Next(1,11))?

Comment: It generates a random number between a min and a max, being the second one exclusive, so in this case a number between 1 and 10. See [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

At present you are setting the random number, but then not changing it on each iteration of the loop. remove the `CInt(Int((6 * Rnd()) + 1))` declaration before the loop and place it in the loop

```
For index = 0 to 9
    value = CInt(Int((6 * Rnd()) + 1))
    Console.writeline(value)
Next
```

Comment: Seems that someone is downvoting answers because the code doesn't use `System.Random`, regardless of whether the code works or not.

Comment: @Steven Liekens Yep - OP asked for his problem to be solved, not for his program to be re written differently...

Comment: @StevenLiekens All the answers were downvoted, even mine and the question itself

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're just declaring the value once. You need to declare a new random value on each iteration.

Try:

```
Dim value As Integer
Dim index As Integer
For index = 0 to 9 
    value = CInt(Int((6 * Rnd()) + 1))
    Console.writeline(value)
Next
```